# Как правильно пользоваться исключениями?

Tags: исключения, php

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пользоваться исключениями?

Читал на хабре и в интернете, с одной стороны есть мнение, что не стоит пользоваться исключениями в классах из соображений инкапсуляции, с другой - не стоит использовать исключения где попало.

Не могу решить, как быть.

Есть скрипт, принимающий XML от 1с и обрабатывающий его.

В случае ошибки выполнения или невалидности данных мне нужно записать это в лог файл и , по возможности, продолжить работу.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это самое то для использования исключений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей описанной задаче конечно же разумно использовать исключения, нежели просто выводить ошибку или вообще ее игнорировать.
Обработка исключений безусловно хорошая вещь, однако и злоупотреблять ей не стоит, т.е. жмакать try catch везде и всюду. Пользоваться этим инструментом надо грамотно. На мой взгляд есть два основных правила тспользования исключений:
 1. Используйте исключения там, где это действительно необходимо - как написал товарищ [@SoloMio](/users/10292/solomio) в своем ответе - используйте исключения для исключительных ситуаций.
 2. Генерация самого исключения и обработка ошибок должны находиться на разных уровнях

Старайтесь также максимально подробно описывать произошедшую ошибку, а не просто: возникла ошибка, спасибо за внимание! (или отгадай где )) ).

Comment: Кстати да, невнятные сообщения от исключений бесят больше всего.

Comment: @SoloMio, люто плюсую!

Answer (score 2):

Я бы пользовался исключениями в такой ситуации, когда в ходе выполнения кода может сложиться неоднозначная ситуация.

Для большей чистоты кода и исключения return hell также можно использовать исключения. Посмотрите, как устроен язык python. После шпш было дико неудобно им пользоваться, но потом проникся)

Answer (score 1):

Исключения - для исключительных ситуаций.

Если невалидность данных - это стандартная ситуация, которая просто требует дополнительной обработки, то делайте просто дполнительный обработчик, который будет парсить эти данные и писать какие-то данные в файл.
Но если невалидные данные - это исключительная ситуация (или обработка таких данных может привести к выбросу исключения), то да, обрабатывайте как исключение.
Ошибка выполнения - это тоже, по-сути, нарушение нормального хода программы, которая тоже должна как-то обрабатываться (хотя, возможно, в вашей программе ее и нельзя будет назвать исключительной ситуацией).